# Ordinary primes for a weak form corresponding to a CM newform

Tags: reference-request, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms, maass-forms

**Setup:** Let $f$ be a harmonic Maass form of weight $2-k$ ($k \in \mathbb{N}$), level $N$, and character $\chi$. Letting $q := e^{2\pi i z}$ and considering the Fourier expansion of any harmonic Maass form in $q$, the differential operator $D := q\cdot \frac{d}{dq} = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \frac{d}{dz}$ has the property $D^{k-1}(f) \in M^{!}_{k}(N, \chi)$. Denote $F := D^{k-1}(f)$. It is well-known that the image of the "shadow operator" $\xi = \xi_{k-1}: f \mapsto \xi(f) =: g$ belongs to $S_{k}(N, \overline{\chi})$.

Call the Maass form $f$ *good* for the CM newform $g$ if its principal part at $\infty$ belongs to $\mathbb{Q}(\text{coeff's of } g)[q^{-1}]$, its principal part at any other cusp is constant, and $f$'s shadow is $g/\langle g, g \rangle$. [This is basically the definition, but I'm assuming the coefficients of $g$ are real.] In this case, $F = D^{k-1}(f)$ has coefficients lying in $\mathbb{Q}(\text{coeff's of } g)$.

In view of [this paper by Jin-Ma-Ono](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.06725), If we assume $g \in S_{k}(N, \chi)$ is a normalized CM newform and $f$ is good for $g$, **what can we say about (non)ordinary primes for the coefficients of $F$?** Are there any results determining whether $a_{F}(p)$ is divisible by $p$ or not? Would this depend on the weight (e.g. $k = 2$ or $k > 2$) or level?

Comment: Paper by Jin, Ma, and Ono???

Comment: @2734364041 Yes, thank you very much. I just edited to give credit to all authors.